# Userform automatically resizes 80% of requested width/height and changes aspect ratio

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am creating a userform with some simple buttons and dropdowns. When I am in the VBA editor messing with the userforms height and width properties, the number I enter will automatically change to roughly 80% of the entered value once I press enter. For example, if I type 500 into the Width field and hit enter, the Width will instead change to 399.6 and the height will change to ~80% of whatever it was set to as well. It happens the other way around too (setting height instead of width). It doesn't seem to affect anything when I change the size in the code and I can change the size by dragging the corner just fine too. But sometimes this will affect how everything shows up when running and actually using the userform.

Other weird things are happening when actually using the userform as well. The biggest being that a listbox seems to overstep the boundaries it is given. There is a dead white space to the right and below this listbox that makes it look like maybe the listbox is shrinking by 80% too but the dead white space was the original size (even though the size I set is what appears and the white space is beyond that).

Any ideas on what might be wrong? I'm to the point where I might just trash the current file and copy/paste everything into a new file.

EDIT: I accidentally put combobox in the second paragraph when it is actually a listbox

Comment: What version of Excel is this, and does a new `UserForm` on a new workbook behave the same way?

Comment: It is 32bit Excel 2016 as part of Office 365. I just tried it on a brand new workbook with nothing but a blank userform and it does the exact same thing. I have built other userforms with this version of excel but never ran into this.

Comment: Is it an insider build? Which *specific* build version number? This should probably be addressed with the "send feedback / send a frown" feature - Microsoft Excel product team *does* monitor these closely!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just sent some feedback. The specific build version is 1807, build 10325.20082

Comment: If you can, try to see if you can get an insider build - IIRC the July (or was it June?) build was 1808, so it might have been fixed already. That said, I don't think this question is a particular good fit for SO, given it's not quite a *programming* question. Cheers!